# Default "Cluster Group" showing offline in SQL Cluster

Tags: sql-server, windows-clustering

I've been trying to find out why the default "cluster group" is showing as offline when I run `Get-ClusterGroup`.

It shows Available Storage and Cluster Group. I found that "Available Storage" is offline because there is no unused cluster disk.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't really related to the SQL _language_,)

Comment: I'm running SQL server 2017 on a Windows Server 2016 Failover Cluster Manager

Comment: I don't think that we will ever know. Have you tried starting the cluster group (`Get-ClusterGroup 'cluster group' | start-clustergroup;`)? If it starts, you're good. If not, you should have some messages in the cluster log about why it wasn't started. Also, if it does start, I'd suggest moving it around using `Move-ClusterGroup -Node ...` to each of the nodes in the cluster that you'd expect to be able to own it.

Comment: @BenThul I guess I was not clear in my query. I'm not looking to start it; I want to know why it exists?